# Readable Directory in Netbeans but Not when Run from JAR File

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have been able to get resources to load in both Netbeans and a JAR file, such as ImageIcons, but today I am unable to "read" from same directory when running my program from a JAR file. I want to list the directories and files in a classpath directory, but when I run the program from a JAR file the directory becomes unreadable. It works fine in Netbeans.

`tileDirectory = new File(TileDirectoryLister.class.getResource("/resources/images/tiles").getPath());`

```
    jta.append("\nThe class path for the tile directory is:"
            + "\n\t" + tileDirectory.getPath());

    jta.append("\nThe tile directory is readable: " + tileDirectory.canRead());
```

When run from Netbeans it prints true; when run from a JAR file it prints false. **Why does `canRead` print `false` when I run from a JAR file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A File represents a path on the file system. Your icons are inside a jar file. You can't use a File to access them.

To get access to some resource in the jar file, just use

```
SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/tiles/SomeIcon.png");
```

to get an InputStream, or

```
SomeClass.class.getResource("/resources/images/tiles/SomeIcon.png");
```

to get a URL.